# Not Understanding why I am receiving 'Subscript Out Of Range'

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on this code in which I have a userform that has a mashup of listboxes and comboboxes. So far I have populated the listboxes but for some reason I am having trouble with the comboboxes (`combobox1` and `combobox2`).

I have managed to populate the drop-down list for `combobox1`, and from that list I want to 'filter' through a named range that is already called out through the 'name manager'. The named range is called `Range_Books`.

`Range_Books` references two columns and a variable number of rows in `table48` on sheet `BOOKS` or in VBA code `Sheet7`. The code below is my latest iteration of attempting to accomplish what I have explained but it still has failed.

I originally was attempting to call out the range directly without the `Worksheets("Sheet7").` since the named range is not on a specific sheet, but I am still not sure which is the best way to call out the range and if that is the root of my problem. I have called out the range directly without the `worksheets(" ")` before which is why I am so perplexed by this.

It may be important to note that when the userform is initialized, it opens a secondary workbook in order to populate the listboxes. After initialization, various actions may be done before a value is chosen for `combobox1`, and thus activating the function I am trying to create. This secondary workbook stays open until the userform is closed. I mention this because I am unsure if the secondary workbook is causing issues with the range object. I have been receiving trouble from VBA since adding the opening of a secondary workbook functionality to the userform.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

count = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Rows.count

For i = 0 To count

    If Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox1.Value Then
        ComboBox2.AddItem (Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Cells(i, 2))
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no row 0 when you do `.cells(i,1)`

Comment: You say that range_books is on a different workbook, You may need to add one more reference to the beginning of each.  You may need to put `Workbooks()` before your `worksheets("Sheet7")...`  The workbook you think is active may have lost its focus.

Comment: Scott actually read the words XD

Comment: I think I see the overlying issue - I think it's how you're referring to your worksheet named "Books".  See my answer below for more info - hopefully that's it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either start with `For i = 1 to count`, or change the ranges to `.Cells(i+1,1)...`

Also, make sure you're referring to the correct sheet.  I think this is where the crux of your issue is.

If your named range is in a worksheet with the tab name "Books", then you need to instead use `count = Worksheets("Books").Range("Range_Books").Rows.count`

If you want to use the "Sheet7" reference instead, you could use `count = Sheet7.Range("Range_Books").Rows.count`

Comment: That is a good catch, and something that I overlooked. I did try this and it still gave me the Subscript out of Range error, highligting line: "Count = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Rows.Count"

Comment: @BryanWatras - Silly question perhaps, but your range `"Range_Books"` is on the `Sheets("Sheet7")` worksheet, yeah?  **OH** I think I see what your confusion is.  Try using `count = Worksheets("Books").Range("Range_Books").Rows.count`.  `Sheets("Sheet7")` is *not* necessarily the same as `Sheet7.Cells(...`  If your worksheet name is "Books", then use `Sheets("Books")`.  If it's the seventh sheet added to the workbook, then `Sheet7.Cells(1,1)` would be the same as `Sheets("Books").Cells(1,1)`.

Comment: I changed all instances of Worksheets("Books") or Worksheets("Sheet7") to jsut Sheet7 and it works perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 0 To count
...
Cells(i, 1)
```

at this point, i = 0. Row 0 Doesn't exist.

Change `i = 0` to `i = 1`

Comment: fwiw, `.Cells(0, 1)` can be referenced as long as `.Cells(1, 1)` is not in the first row. It's the same as saying `.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0)`. If the **Range_Books** named range started in row 2, this would be a legitimate call but if it starts in row 1 then you are requesting a cell that does not exist (e.g. pushed off the top of the worksheet).

Comment: That is a good catch, and something that I overlooked. I did try this and it still gave me the Subscript out of Range error, highligting line: "Count = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Rows.Count"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As WorkSheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet7")
count = ws.Range("Range_Books").Rows.count

For i = 1 To count

    If Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox1.Value Then
        ComboBox2.AddItem (Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Cells(i, 2))
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That is a good catch, and something that I overlooked. I did try this and it still gave me the Subscript out of Range error, highligting line: "Count = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Range_Books").Rows.Count"

Comment: Please check if you have a Range "Range_Books" in Sheet7

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help, it is very much appreciated! My final working code is below. I changed all instances of Worksheets("Sheet7") to just Sheet7. I attached a picture of the Excel Objects folder tree, as you can see I have Sheet7 which I named "Books". My confusion was that Worksheets(" ") calls out the name I assign rather than the VBA assigned name for the sheet. I also added ComboBox2.Clear that way whenever ComboBox1 changes it resets the values rather then stacking them. I hope this helps somebody in the future and thanks again to the commentors who helped me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfGq5.jpg)

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

ComboBox2.Clear

Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

count = Sheet7.Range("Range_Books").Rows.count

For i = 1 To count

    If Sheet7.Range("Range_Books").Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox1.Value Then
        ComboBox2.AddItem (Sheet7.Range("Range_Books").Cells(i, 2))
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```